# Calling property of One Function From Inside Another Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using functions as representations of classes.

```
function ClassOne()
{
  this.doFunc = function() {
    console.log("doFunc output");
  }
}

function ClassTwo()
{
  this.one = ClassOne();
  console.log(this.one); // == undefined ???

  this.init = function() {
    this.one.doFunc();
  }

  this,init();
}

ClassTwo();
```

But I'm struggling to use one function inside another.

For example, the above code returns "Cannot read property 'doFunc' of undefined"

Why is this.one == undefined?

Comment: _**Why is this.one == undefined?**_: Because you are executing the function and the function has no `return` statement. Therefore, it returns `undefined` and assigns that to your `this.one` property.

Comment: You need to use `new ClassOne()` is you want it to make an instance for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign to a property of `this` inside a function, generally that indicates that the function is intended to be called as a constructor with `new`, eg:

```
this.one = new ClassOne();
```

Otherwise, if the function doesn't return anything... then, well, nothing gets returned  (=> `undefined`)

```js
function ClassOne()
{
  this.doFunc = function() {
    console.log("doFunc output");
  }
}

function ClassTwo()
{
  this.one = new ClassOne();
  console.log(this.one);

  this.init = function() {
    this.one.doFunc();
  }

  this.init();
}

ClassTwo();
```

Or, you can have `ClassOne` explicitly return an object with a `doFunc` property, allowing it to be called without `new`:

```
function ClassOne()
{
  return {
    doFunc() {
      console.log("doFunc output");
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function ClassOne() {
  return {
    doFunc() {
      console.log("doFunc output");
    }
  }
}

function ClassTwo() {
  this.one = ClassOne();
  console.log(this.one);

  this.init = function() {
    this.one.doFunc();
  }

  this.init();
}

ClassTwo();
```